# how to unzip to a differently-named file

Tags: linux, zip

I need to unzip to a file.txt (not a folder or anything else)

something like that:

```
unzip test.zip -d >> file.txt
```

test.zip contain a single file called "x.txt". I do not want to uncompress as "x.txt". I need send out direct to an another file called "file.txt"

Comment: What's wrong with just `unzip test.zip`?

Comment: within the archive is a text file called "x.txt". I want instead decompressing as "x.txt" send the file contents to the output "file.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to check the man page.  Even just the `--help` flag mentions what you need.

```
unzip -p test.zip > file.txt
```

Comment: update the question to more clear what i want. Thanks